# How to loop concatenate for Outlook's Bcc with VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

The code works fine! except for one problem I have with the section ccomment 'THIS LINE is ignoring the sequence.

This line is supposed to apply the concatenate to rows from 809 to 1608 in the second loop, as example; but Instead, it concatenate from 9 to 1608.

Third loop? from 9 to 2408 INSTEAD of 1609 to 2408.

And so on. It figures out the endref correctly. But there is a problem with the startref.
What I am doing wrong?
How to fix this so each x concatenate the following 800 rows as planned?
Thanks!
If you want to try the code, here it is:
[enter link description here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TBJL20PwGjlx5zZvRrYqR1NXq2cvhQaX/view?usp=sharing)

```
Sub Mailer()

    Sheets("Data").Select
    Range("A5").Value = 0
    Range("A6").Value = 5
    Range("A7").Value = 9
    Range("A8").Value = 808
    Range("G2").Value = ""
       
    loopref = Sheets("Data").Range("A4").Value
    
    For x = 1 To loopref
    
If Sheets("Data").Range("A5").Value < Sheets("Data").Range("A4").Value Then
       
    'autos
    howlong = Sheets("Data").Range("A6").Value
    startref = Sheets("Data").Range("A7").Value
    endref = Sheets("Data").Range("A8").Value
       
    
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim i As String
    Dim SourceRange As Range

    
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''THIS LINE is ignoring the sequence
    Set SourceRange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("B" & startref & ":B" & endref)

    
    For Each rng In SourceRange
    i = i & rng & "; "
    Next rng
    Sheets("Data").Range("G2").Value = Trim(i)


    Sheets("Welcome").Select
    Dim wd As Object, editor As Object
    Dim doc As Object
    Dim oMail As MailItem
    
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Object 1")).Select
    Selection.Verb Verb:=xlPrimary
    Set wd = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
    Set doc = ActiveDocument
    doc.Content.Copy
    doc.Close
    Set wd = Nothing

     Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
     Set oMail = OutApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
     With oMail
        .Display
        .BCC = Sheets("Data").Range("G2").Value
        .Subject = "Type your subject here"
        .BodyFormat = olFormatRichText
        Set editor = .GetInspector.WordEditor
        editor.Content.Paste
        .DeferredDeliveryTime = DateAdd("n", howlong, VBA.Now)
        .Send
    End With
    
    'adjust autos
    Sheets("Data").Range("A5").Value = Sheets("Data").Range("A5").Value + 1
    Sheets("Data").Range("A6").Value = Sheets("Data").Range("A6").Value + 60
    Sheets("Data").Range("A7").Value = Sheets("Data").Range("A7").Value + 800
    Sheets("Data").Range("A8").Value = Sheets("Data").Range("A8").Value + 800
    Sheets("Data").Range("G2").ClearContents
    
    
    'reset if exceeds
    If Sheets("Data").Range("A7").Value > 99209 Then
    Sheets("Data").Range("A7").Value = 9
    End If
    
    If Sheets("Data").Range("A8").Value > 100008 Then
    Sheets("Data").Range("A7").Value = 808
    End If

End If
    Next x

MsgBox "Sent to Outbox!"
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
MsgBox "Sent to outbox!"

End Sub
```

Comment: Step through your code using F8 to check the value of those variables.

Comment: It works until outlook can't handly more bcc.. it is ignoring my sequence. It should take 800 rows each x. it figures out the ending row correctly. but it fails to figure out the starting row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to reset i to Null String in every loop

```
'autos
    howlong = Sheets("Data").Range("A6").Value
    startref = Sheets("Data").Range("A7").Value
    endref = Sheets("Data").Range("A8").Value
    i=""
```

Comment: I knew it... I knew two things. (1) I am noob. and (2) There is some1 awesome out there will get it ... wow.. it solved my problem. I just needed to remove this Too: 
Dim i as String 
Thanks from the heart!